# Why are my post script commands not getting passed the LaTeX compiler?

Tags: pstricks, postscript

The following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
  \rput{!240 6 div}(0,0){Hello World}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

is not able to parse the post script command.  Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\usepackage{pstricks}
\SpecialCoor% activate !, *, >, **, ;, and |
...
```

the other question, where you have to strip the dimension:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\SpecialCoor
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
  \rput{!\number\paperheight\space \number\paperwidth\space 
    atan }(2,3){Hello World}
  \rput[lb](0,1){\the\paperwidth : \number\paperwidth}
  \rput[lb](0,0){\the\paperheight : \number\paperheight}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`\the\paperwidth` is in pt and `\number\paperwidth` in sp (scaled point) 1pt=65536sp

Comment: So, I need to activate `\SpecialCoor` even to use post scripts?  I don't usually do that, but then again I usually call `pst-eucl` and other packages which might.

Comment: Some packages do it for you, eg `pst-eucl`, `pstricks-add`, ...

Comment: I suppose I could ask this in a second, but when I'm trying to pass something like `\rput{! \paperheight\space \paperwidth\space div}(...)` even with `\SpecialCoor`, I'm getting a post script error about `/undefined in \paperheight`.  Why aren't my macros getting converted to the appropriate lengths before the postscript compiler sees them?  (Or should I just ask this as a new question?)

Comment: actually it's `arctan` that I want, not `div`

Comment: see extended answer

Comment: Why was `\SpecialCoor` not activated by default so it frees us to do it manually? Does it hurt us?

Comment: on slow machines it maybe take some time to scan values if you have a lot of it (> 1000)

Comment: So it means that other packages that automatically activate `\SpecialCoor` are not for slow machines.

Comment: a slow machine is a processor <486 and a large data set is >1000 records